# Particles/Standard unlit behaving differently in different scenes

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, particle-system

[image]

in scene 1 it is correct, but when I am using this prefab in scene 2 it shows white flash, though all values are same in shader.

Comment: are they also the same in the particle systems?

Comment: yes, they are same.

Comment: and could the animator have something to do with it?

Comment: Go to _Window > Rendering > Lighting Settings_ and make sure the scenes have the same lighting settings.

Comment: Check your camera bloom